# How can I create an XML file in Visual Basic?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was asked to write some code to interface with the Wi-Flight Api in visual basic. I already have code to login and interface with the API.

I am writing some sample code to submit a reservation. To do this, I need to create an xml file and fill it with the appropriate data which will be simply be entered in TextFields for this sample code.

I have found various snippets of code on the internet to create basic files that look like ([source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter-vbnet)):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Employees>
      <Employee>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FirstName>Prakash</FirstName>
        <LastName>Rangan</LastName>
        <Salary>70000</Salary>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <FirstName>Norah</FirstName>
        <LastName>Miller</LastName>
        <Salary>21000</Salary>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <ID>17</ID>
        <FirstName>Cecil</FirstName>
        <LastName>Walker</LastName>
        <Salary>60000</Salary>
      </Employee>
    </Employees>
```

Now, I need to create an xml file that look like [this](https://www.wi-flight.net/docs/api.html#resvobj).

It requires me to put things like

```
    <reservation name="unique-name">
```

I have not found any way to add the name="unique-name" part to the XML file.
I am looking for a way to do this.

Comment: What does your code look like now?  If we can see what you have working already, we can show you where to add the relevant lines.  What you're looking for is an element and an attribute.

Comment: You may want to look into XML serialization. Or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy to do using XDocument/XElement:

```vb
Dim v As XElement = <reservation/>
'or Dim v As XElement = XElement.Parse("<reservation/>")
'or Dim v As XElement = XElement.Load("pathToFile")
v.SetAttributeValue("name", "unique-name")
Debug.WriteLine(v.ToString) 'prints <reservation name="unique-name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

no offence, but don't you think you might be interested in the [documentation of `XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y8188ze.aspx) ? know your tools ...

`xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString( "name", sUniqueName )` is your friend, assuming that `sUniquename` holds the, well, unique name needed.